# How to use gnome keyring under my chroot?

Tags: chroot, gnome-keyring

I have a debian bullseye chroot in which I use svn.
I want to save my password somewhere.
One of the means to do so is to use gnome-keyring password store.
What should I configure in order to allow svn in my chroot to use gnome-keyring?
If possible, I don't want to start gnome-keyring twice.
I currently use Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for my case :

1. allow access to host dbus mounting `/run/user`
2. allow applications in your chroot to locate the bus setting the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable

Step 1 :
I edited `/etc/fstab` and added the following line :

```
/run/user/<your UID> /<path_to_the_chroot_root_directory>/run/user/<your UID> auto bind 0 0
```

You need to replace  with your UID and <path_to_the_chroot_root_directory> with the path to the root directory of your chroot.

To apply before reboot, remount :

```
sudo mount -a
```

I do not know if this mount breaches security.

Step 2 :
A long time ago, for a reason, I've emptied `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable in my `~/.bashrc`. I've just have to comment out this line.

If your variable is not yet set, this will do :

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus
```

But having the variable unset looks like an evidence of another issue you may want to dig for a solution.